# why does 手段を選ばない = will do anything?

Tags: expressions

why does 手段を選ばない = will do anything?

Answer (score 6):

It means they're not choosy about the means they use to reach a target. They don't choose their means or measures, they'll do anything to get where they want to.

The first time I heard this, I thought it was weird too. I thought that by "not choosing any means", one would end up doing nothing, but I guess it makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 3):

選ばない here can mean "not picky, not bothering to choose", or in other words, indiscriminately. There is a similar idiom in Chinese I'm pretty sure, although I don't know which one came first since they both date only back to the 19th century it seems.